# How to use expression-based access control in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am new to spring.I have created an api for user login.The user login method contains following codes:

```
Authentication auth =new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(repo.findByEmail(user.getEmail()), null, repo.findByEmail(user.getEmail()).getAuthorities());

SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
Principal principal= SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
return (User) auth.getPrincipal();
```

The login api gives me the following json:

```
{
"userId": 1,
"userName": "ramesh khadka",
"email": "test@gmail.com",
"enabled": true,
"role": "Manager",
"username": "ramesh khadka",
"authorities": [
    {
        "authority": "ROLE_Manager"
    }
],
"accountNonExpired": true,
"accountNonLocked": true,
"credentialsNonExpired": true
}
```

I have another api to get all the users that uses @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_Manager')") to check the authorities granted.When I call the api following message is shown:-

```
{
"error": "unauthorized",
"error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.Could someone help me on this?

My AuthorizationServer is:-

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class SecurityServer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
@Qualifier("userDetailsService")
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
    security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    // super.configure(clients);
    clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("test")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600)
            .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code","refresh_token","password","client_credentials")
            .secret("user")
            .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
            .redirectUris("/error")
            .resourceIds("resource");
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
    endpoints.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return bean;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you add your spring security configuration?

Comment: @AnupamaBoorlagadda I have included my security code

Answer (score 0):

As described in your code you have use '@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_Manager')")'

hasAuthority([authority])   --> Returns true if the current principal has the specified authority.

please add '@PreAuthorize("hasRole('Manager')") `

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
public void create(Contact contact);
```

either you may use this to is their any role you 
are looking for and then check 
 hasAnyRole([role1,role2])  --> Returns true if the current principal has any of the supplied roles (given as a comma-separated list of strings). By default if the supplied role does not start with 'ROLE_' it will be added. This can be customized by modifying the defaultRolePrefix on DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.

For more you may refer to these links:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html
https://dzone.com/refcardz/expression-based-authorization